# masscan не видит открытые порты

Tags: linux, сеть

Есть IP vnc сервера, известен порт 5900, подключаюсь всё работает. Прошу masscan прочекать этот IP на открытые порты - не находит, втыкаю этот IP в шодан - тоже не видит, но он то есть, как понять такое поведение ? и как это поведение обойти ?

Comment: желательно подтвердить свои слова выводами команд...

Comment: sudo masscan -p5090 52.24.12.145
[sudo] пароль для dr3lo: 

Starting masscan 1.0.6 (http://bit.ly/14GZzcT) at 2018-04-12 19:08:41 GMT
 -- forced options: -sS -Pn -n --randomize-hosts -v --send-eth
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan
Scanning 1 hosts [1 port/host]

Comment: 1) порт не тот 2) лучше добавить в вопрос, чтобы глаза не ломать 3) то что порт действительно открыт лучше подтвердить netstat'ом на строне сервера... или просто постучаться, скажем netcat'ом..

Comment: да, по умолчанию вывод пишется не на консоль,а в `scan.xml`

Comment: а где этот файлик валяется ?

Comment: в текущем каталоге должен быть, но задать можно `--output-filename`